# Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen()

Tags: php, yii2

Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen()

..\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseStringHelper.php

Пользуюсь Denwer, php 5.5.27

Comment: Через phpinfo() проверьте Loaded Configuration File C:\...\php.ini

Answer (score 1):

`mb_strlen()` не включена изначально в **php** 
вы можете исправить это тут

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Comment: в php.ini раскомментировал extension=php_mbstring.dll и в папке ext есть php_mbstring.dll. Перезапускал сервер

Comment: у Вас может быть несколько php.ini. убедитесь что правите необходимый

Comment: Один файл. Когда я убрал комментарий, то при запуске сервера появлялось два раза одно и тоже окно с надписью PHP startup